# Adding an external Wi-Fi antenna to Android phone

Tags: wi-fi

Looking to use external Wi-Fi stick with Android phone to allow use of external Wi-Fi antenna.  Prefer not to access connector under cover because it requires modification of phone.  Drivers exist for Windows allowing this to be done, but cannot find driver for Android.